# Limit of $\frac{\sin 2x}{x}$ when $x \to 0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

My teacher solved this:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin 2x}{2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

I have problem with this part:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin 2x}{2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

which is equal to

$$\frac{2 \sin 2x}{2x} = \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: It's wrong. You have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin (2x)}{2x} = 1$, so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin (2x)}{x} = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sin (2x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sin (2x)}{x} \frac{2}{2} = \lim_{2x \to 0} \frac{ \sin (2x)}{2x} \times 2 = 1 \times 2 = 2$$

If $x$ tends to $0$, then $2x$ also tends to zero.

And the problem follows by using the formula:

$$ \lim_{t \to 0 } \frac{\sin (t)}{t} = 1 $$

In general $$ \lim_{t \to 0} 
\frac{ \sin (nt) }{t} = n  $$

Comment: Is there a formula which says sinx / x = 1?

Comment: yes there is a fomula

Comment: The "formula" is usually one of the earliest results in this topic. Some books use the "squeeze" theorem to demonstrate the formula. The "x" in the denominator must be the same as the "x" in the argument of sine, which is why you have to have "2x inside" and "2x on the bottom" in the third expression in the string of equalities above.